# Confusion About Deleting Documents in MongoDB Capped Collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm hoping for sort out why I'm not seeing what I'd expect in a MongoDB capped collection. According to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#document-deletion):

> You cannot delete documents from a capped collection. To remove all documents from a collection, use the  [`drop()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#mongodb-method-db.collection.drop)  method to drop the collection and recreate the capped collection.

However, I am able to delete documents from my capped collection, from what it seems?

Using `MongoDB 6.0.1`:

```
test> db.createCollection("cappyMcCapCap", { "capped": true, "size": 100000, "max": 100 } )
{ ok: 1 }

test> db.cappyMcCapCap.isCapped()
true
```

So far so good, now I'll insert two documents:

```
test> db.cappyMcCapCap.insertOne({ "hat": "bowler" });
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: ObjectId("63a4c2dffe0ea68c13a8c265")
}

test> db.cappyMcCapCap.insertOne({ "hat": "newsboy" });
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: ObjectId("63a4c2e9fe0ea68c13a8c266")
}
```

And then delete the *newer* of the two documents:

```
test> db.cappyMcCapCap.deleteOne({ "hat": "newsboy" });
{ acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1 }
```

Which is successful?

```
test> db.cappyMcCapCap.find();
[ { _id: ObjectId("63a4c2dffe0ea68c13a8c265"), hat: 'bowler' } ]
```

I seem to remember maybe getting an error in the past, but I have not tried manually deleting documents from a capped collection in a while.

So is that documentation correct, or am I misunderstanding something?

**UPDATE**

---

I also tried this in MongoDB `5.0.14` with the same results (I could delete documents).

However then I tried MongoDB  `4.2.23` and got a:

```
... "errmsg" : "cannot remove from a capped collection: test.cappyMcCapCap"
```

As I had expected. It seems like this has changed in the more recent versions?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/confusion-about-deleting-documents-in-capped-collections/205495/5) in the MongoDB Forums:

> I have indeed reproduced and scaled it internally. I want to inform you that MongoDB > 5.0 removed the restriction on delete operations in the apply operations command.
>
> However, we don’t seem to have added this to the documentation yet. I’ve filed an internal ticket to update the documentation to reflect this to avoid confusion.

So with MongoDB `5.0` and up you can now delete documents from a capped collection.